# uwamp use 1-2% cpu while doing nothing in the system tray

Tags: uwamp

With mysql and php 7.1.x running, no trafic on the server, uwamp.exe uses 2-3% CPU on an A8-7600 just sitting in the system tray.

I would guess it's a bug?

Answer (score 1):

I've noticed the same thing.  I think it's a bug.  I'm guessing this is due to the CPU and memory usage monitoring from the uwamp console.  It doesn't look like this can be disabled from uwamp.ini.

However, there is a workaround.  If you attempt to close the uwamp console, but do not close the Apache and MySQL processes, the uwamp console process is closed and the CPU usage goes back to normal.  You can still use the server, however you lose the management capabilities of the console.